# NLU FastText, Glove or Word2Vec Load Pre-trained model and Add new word to vocabulary

Tags: neural-network, nlp, word2vec, gensim, fasttext

As i say in the title i would like to load pre-tranined model

using gensim is possibile for example but with fasttext say:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/wrappers/fasttext.html

```
 "Note that due to limitations in the FastText API, you cannot continue training with a model loaded this way, though you can query for word similarity etc."
```

With Word2vec say it is possibile continue the traning of your own model not a pretranind end i do not know with Glove.

Can you point me to any library or something for load a pre-tranined model and continue the traning on my own sentences ?

Or in case i can load the pretranined model into a neural network and after continue the traning with my own vectors ?  (maybe using get_keras_embedding ? )